# android location listener two functions Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-service, locationlistener

I am working on an app that runs a service that has a location listener, and needs to do things in the background.

I am currently integrating Google Maps in my app, do I need to create a different location listener? Do I use the same one, how?

If someone can point me in the right direction for the right way to do it, I would greatly appreciate it...

Comment: what are you trying to do with the location?

Comment: I am storing the locations for future use through the service, and I want the map to show the current location. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using google maps v2 just set `setMyLocationEnabled(boolean)` to true and it will display your location without you having to do anything

Comment: It does not work for me... Don't I need to send a location source (location listener) to the map?

Answer (score 1):

In your location Listener, wherever you get your location, you use the googleMaps change position method call.

```
 googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(position));
```

position would be instantiated like so:

```
 LatLng position = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
```

That should do what you want it to do.  Spend some time looking at the developer guide for google maps.